# Gerar javadoc de testes com Maven no NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, javadoc

Preciso gerar javadoc de testes usando Maven.

Encontrei este tutorial => https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/test-javadocs.html

Ele funcionou, porém, só consigo gerar javadoc via terminal, usando o comando:

> mvn javadoc:test-javadoc

Alguém saberia uma forma de gerar no Netbeans?

Comment: Com Maven ou com Netbeans? Ou quer gerar automaticamente ao gerar um .jar ou .war?

Comment: No seu `pom.xml`, *right click*  -> *Run maven*, na janela que aparecer, coloque algo como `compile  javadoc:test-javadoc` (é o *lifecycle* que tu precisar na verdade) em *Goals*, marque *Remember as*, bote um nome e este *run* ficará salvo pra usar depois

Comment: Olá Bruno. Eu gostaria de gerar o javadoc dos testes no Netbeans. Você saberia se é possível criar um perfil para gerar os javadocs dos testes? Dessa forma, todos que fizer clone do meu projeto, poderão gerar a documentação dos testes.

Comment: Perfil no netbeans ou perfil do maven? Se do maven, basta criar um e definir o `javadoc:test-javadoc` como `defaultGoal`, se for preciso ativado por padrão. Para rodar, `mvn -Ptest-javadoc`, ou apenas `mvn` se tiver ativo por padrão. Se tiver mais alguma coisa, atualize sua pergunta com mais detalhes que incluo uma resposta, invés de comentários.

Comment: Era isso mesmo o que eu precisava. Obrigado pela ajuda!